# how to fetch data from json using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have my sample data like this

```
var contacts = [{
    id: 0,
    'name': 'john',
        'email': 'hello@gmail.com',
        'phone': '123-2343-44'
}];
```

Instead using this way, how do i fetch the data from a json file using angularjs?

Comment: from a json file?. Where is the file located?

Comment: i exported the mysql data with php.http://localhost/contacts/all, this would be the link

Comment: then @mgnb has your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

In short, if for instance the json endpoint is at the same web domain at /contacts_endpoint.json, include $http in your controller/service/whatever and run

```
angular.module('myModule').controller(function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('/contacts_endpoint.json').success(function(contacts) {
    // the variable contacts contains the data you want 
  });
});
```

Comment: this seems to working fine too, using this method, i am able to use the same variable name used in the rest of the program

      `var url = 'http://localhost/contacts';
       contacts = {};
       contacts.getConacts = function()
       {
        return $http.get(url + '/all');
       }`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your JSON is not valid.
Provided you have a valide one just write

```
var objectFromJSON = JSON.parse(validJSON);
```

and access any part of original JSON you want to.

Comment: i exported the mysql data with php.http://localhost/contacts/all, this would be the link

Comment: OK, I thought you wanted to know how to fetch something from the JSON instead of fetching a JSON itself. To do that just follow @mgnb's answer

Comment: ya, i wanted to fetch the entire data from a json file. thanks a lot